# Dimension Object Advantages & Disadvantages?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe

When using a `JFrame`, I noticed some people spent their time doing

```
 setSize(new Dimension(400,400));
```

rather than simply

```
setSize(400,400);
```

Are there any particular advantages to using the prior rather than the latter if not storing the object in a variable?

Also, can I not draw directly in `JFrame`? do I need a canvas for it? is it simply best to extend `Canvas`? no `JComponent` alternative to `Canvas`?

Comment: The JComponent alternative to Canvas is JPanel.  Just remember to override paintComponent, not paint, and make sure the first line in your paintComponent method is a call to super.paintComponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When using a JFrame, I noticed some people spent their time doing
>
> ```
> setSize(new Dimension(400,400));
> ```
>
> rather than simply
>
> ```
> setSize(400,400);
> ```
>
> Are there any particular advantages to using the prior rather than the
>   latter if not storing the object in a variable?

No.  Basically it's just a connivance so you don't need to do something like...

```
Dimension dim = new Dimension(400, 400);
setSize(dim.width, dim.height);
```

You could just do

```
setSize(dim);
```

Having said that, you shouldn't rely on it, as `pack` will produce better results, if you've build you base components properly...

> Also, can I not draw directly in JFrame? do I need a canvas for it?

Generally, no, you shouldn't paint directly to the frame, there are a number of important reasons why, to start with, `JFrame` (and other top level containers) are not double buffered, so repaints will flicker, also, the frame decorations are painted WITHIN the frame, so if you paint directly to the frame, you run the risk of painting under the decorations...

For example...

- [How to get the EXACT middle of a screen, even when re-sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457237/how-to-get-the-exact-middle-of-a-screen-even-when-re-sized/13460914#13460914)
- [Graphics rendering in title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313084/graphics-rendering-in-title-bar/13316131#13316131)
- [How can I set in the midst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734069/how-can-i-set-in-the-midst/13734319#13734319)

And just because I can't be bothered typing it again...

- [Why is overriding paint in a top-level container so bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157956/why-is-overriding-paint-in-a-top-level-container-so-bad/17158482#17158482)

> is it simply best to extend Canvas? no JComponent alternative to Canvas?

This depends on your needs.  `Canvas` is a heavy weight component, so adding it to a `JFrame` can cause problems.  It is also not double buffered, so either you need to implement a `BufferStrategy` or implement your own double buffering...

And no, there is no Swing alternative to `Canvas`, but remember, Swing components are double buffered already and (at least since Java 6...I think), support hard ware acceleration through either Direct3D or OpenGL where available...

Comment: @nachokk It's much easier when you're not typing on an iPad at 530 in the morning ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you so much! However, if I wanted to work in the future in 3D game development, what do you recommend for graphics? just standard canvas and JFrame?

Comment: If I recall correctly, most 3D libraries utilise there own rendering component (which I believe is based on a heavy weight component), so there's no real benefit either way. General rule of thumb is, don't mix heavy and light weight components