# Painting on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have a class that extends JFrame with ten radio buttons on it, and I've used a variety of JPanels and GridLayouts to help me place them correctly. I'm attempting to make it so that when you select a combination of radio buttons, the program will draw a line between each of the radio buttons in the order you've selected them. However, I can't get anything to appear. I'm not sure if I'm not overridding the right method, if I should be using Graphics2D, if the panels are hiding whatever I'm drawing...preferably, I'd like a solution that doesn't have me overriding a JPanel or something like that.

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.update(g);
    if(buttonsSelected>1)
    {
        g.setColor(new Color(0xE3, 0xC9, 0x39));
        for(int k=0;k>4&&lastButton[k+1]!=-1;k++)
        {
            g.drawLine(buttonTest[lastButton[k]].getX(), buttonTest[lastButton[k]].getY(), buttonTest[lastButton[k+1]].getX(), buttonTest[lastButton[k]].getY());
            System.out.println("Ole!");
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, here is part of the code I'm using to draw the panes

```
    int j=0;
    for(int k=0;k<10;k++)
    {
        buttonTest[k]=new JRadioButton();
        buttonTest[k].setActionCommand(Integer.toString(k));
        buttonTest[k].setToolTipText(powersDin[k]);
        buttonTest[k].addActionListener(new GoddessListener());
        buttonTest[k].setEnabled(false);
    }
    buttonTest[0].setEnabled(true);
    buttonTest[6].setEnabled(true);
    buttonTest[9].setEnabled(true);

    paneGrids[0]=new JPanel();
    paneGrids[0].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,7));
    paneGrids[0].add(new JLabel()); //adding a blank JLabel lets me pad out the empty cells I don't want to fill
    paneGrids[0].add(new JLabel());
    paneGrids[0].add(new JLabel());
    paneGrids[0].add(buttonTest[j++]);
    paneGrids[0].add(new JLabel());
    paneGrids[0].add(new JLabel());
    paneGrids[0].add(new JLabel());
```

Comment: you have to override the paint method of every single checkbox! otherwise they will update and delete what you have drawn.

Comment: I'm trying to draw a line between the buttons, not on them exactly. And also, when I run the code, I should be getting "Ole!" on the console, which isn't happening.

Comment: that "Ole!" is shown doesn't surprise me! But a checkbox has a rectangular area around it!

Comment: No, it's not getting shown! And also, I'm using radio buttons (though your point about them being rectangular would probably apply to them as well)

Comment: sry, I skipped that! please provide more code but in a mininmal way (just one checkbox etc.).

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `@Override` annotation on your `paintComponent` method. You will see that you are not overriding any method on your JFrame. It is because `paintComponent` is defined on JComponent which JFrame does not inherit from. Therefore your `paintComponent` method is never called.

Instead of trying to paint on a top-level container ([which should generally not be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17158482/2891664)), use a JPanel for the custom painting.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // your custom painting
}
```

Using a JPanel is no more complicated, just call `yourFrame.setContentPane(yourCustomPanel);`.

If you want to draw *on top of the children* you *can* override `paint` *judiciously*. `paintComponent` will necessarily draw behind the children because it is for drawing the component. `paint` will draw on *everything*. The other option for drawing on top of children is to using something like a glass pane or JLayeredPane which are more difficult to work with.

Here is an MCVE that demonstrates how to do something like I think you are wanting to do simply.

[image: connective grid]

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

class ConnectiveGrid implements Runnable {
    static final int GRID_H = 5;
    static final int GRID_W = 10;

    Map<JCheckBox, Point> path;
    GridPanel grid;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ConnectiveGrid());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Connective Grid");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // (LinkedHashMap will maintain insertion order)
        path = new LinkedHashMap<JCheckBox, Point>();

        grid = new GridPanel();
        ActionListener listener = new Listener();

        for(int i = 0; i < GRID_H * GRID_W; i++) {
            JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox();
            check.addActionListener(listener);
            grid.add(check);
        }

        frame.setContentPane(grid);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class Listener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            Object sc = ae.getSource();
            if(!(sc instanceof JCheckBox)) {
                return;
            }

            JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox)sc;
            if(check.isSelected()) {

                Dimension sz = check.getSize();
                Point pt = check.getLocation();

                pt.x += sz.width / 2;
                pt.y += sz.height / 2;

                // if the check box is selected
                // put it and its associated point in the path
                path.put(check, pt);

            } else {

                // else remove the check box and point
                path.remove(check);
            }

            // prompt a clean repaint
            grid.repaint();
        }
    }

    class GridPanel extends JPanel {
        GridPanel() {
            super(new GridLayout(GRID_H, GRID_W));
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);

            // verify there are enough points to draw at least one line
            if(path.size() < 2) {
                return;
            }

            Graphics2D copy = (Graphics2D)g.create();
            copy.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
            copy.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
            );

            // iterate the path and paint line-by-line
            Iterator<Point> it = path.values().iterator();
            Point prev = it.next();
            do {
                Point next = it.next();

                copy.drawLine(
                    prev.x, prev.y,
                    next.x, next.y
                );

                prev = next;
            } while(it.hasNext());

            copy.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...wait, do I need to convert every single JPanel I want to draw on into a custom JPanel in order for this to work?

Comment: I don't see why you would. I had the impression you were only trying to paint on the container.

Comment: Now it's not displaying some of the buttons. If I use setEnable(false), will it not draw them, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't think disabling a button should have an effect on your custom painting. I including an MCVE that I hope demonstrates how to do something like this correctly.